# How to include all pragma categories except one from autodie?

Tags: perl

I normally load `autodie` by `use autodie ':all'` for all of my Perl scripts.

However, I do not want to include autodie for `system`.

How can I load all autodie categories with the exception of one in particular? Something like `use autodie '!system'` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use autodie;
```

or

```
use autodie ':default';
```